# Get superclasses function in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, superclass

What would be a short functional way to get the superclasses of a given Class instance in Scala?

All I could come up with is this

```
def supers(cl: Class[_]): List[Class[_]] = {
  cl :: Option(cl.getSuperclass).map(supers).getOrElse(Nil)
}
```

Does anyone know a shorter form with some fancy functional constructs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly fancy functional constructs, but (slightly) shorter:

```
def supers(cl: Class[_]): List[Class[_]] = {
    if (cl == null) Nil else cl :: supers(cl.getSuperclass)
}

scala> class Foo; class Bar extends Foo; class Baz extends Bar
defined class Foo
defined class Bar
defined class Baz

scala> supers(classOf[Baz])
res9: List[Class[_]] = List(class Baz, class Bar, class Foo, class java.lang.Object)
```

Note that this gives you the class and all of it's superclasses, but then again so does the one provided by the OP.

Comment: We can get rid of the `null` with `if (cl == classOf[AnyRef]) List(cl)`. Otherwise we might as well take this discussion to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Matthew, Thanks. The compiler might be able to optimize this better than my example.